# Cakephp Dynamic and static binding

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Since long I have a question in mind regarding model relationship of cakephp. I have huge database, having nearly 100s of Models. What I do is make static binding in all my Model then, control my data using Containable behaviour, & recursive in controllers. This is the way I manage my static binding. by creating all sort of relationship in model.

If some binding that is rarely used in that case only I use dynamic binding or binding on the fly. What I do in controller mention all the Model in **$uses** where my find & save can be possible. Does it make my cakePHP processing slow ? Do I use or bind model on the fly? Does binding dynamically affects the performance? Does making static binding make its performance slow ?

Comment: Static will make the system slow at some point not always but binding on fly will give you lots of freedom but it is less documented as you have to add comments for next generation coders of your project. Now choose what you want.

Comment: Dynamic binding is good practice in cake but using **$uses can make your  code slow. try to load model on the fly and use dynamic binding and check the performance. If you have static binding and you don't need them in some cases, you can unbind them as well, which will save some sql queries.